# How to read back collectd and write_kafka plugin

Tags: graphite, collectd, kafka

I want to use `kafka` as a transport layer for `collectd`.  I found that there is a `write_kafka` plugin for `collectd`, which sends all the gathered metrics to a `kafka` topic.

My intention was to have a few hosts as collectors (working as a `kafka` consumer groups) to get those metrics off the topic, and put them into a time-series database (`influxdb` or `graphite`).

`collectd` doesn't have a `kafka` consumer input plugin. `graphite` can't read `kafka` directly either (I think?). What piece of software am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Kafka consumer for InfluxDB written in Python: https://github.com/mre/kafka-influxdb